# Nested property for user control

Tags: c#, asp.net, properties, user-controls

I have created user control and defined all properties. I was able to access/modify the property in design time. Here i need to know how to give nested properties to the same control.

For example consider default property "Font" which have sub properties like "Bold", "Italic" ,"Names" etc. Like this, i need nested properties in my custom control.

[image]

Actually i need like this nested properties for user controls in my web application.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change all properties to dependency properties. For example:

```
 public static DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(Choice));
     public string Text
     {
          get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
          set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
     }

     public static DependencyProperty Choice4Property = DependencyProperty.Register("Choice4", typeof(Choice), typeof(MyControl));
     public Choice Choice4
     {
          get { return (Choice)GetValue(Choice4Property); }
          set { SetValue(Choice4Property, value); }
     }
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion.Please share the code snippet for defn of SetValue and GetValue methods.